# Ui-Router for Angular - Partials html

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, partials

there! I'm trying to use partials, but isn't working:

My html files are created and in place, I can't understand why it doesn't work!

I'm using angular 1.6.4 and ui-router 1.0.0-rc.1

Anyone can help me?

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
.state("home", {
url: "/home",
templateUrl: "home.html",
controller: "HomeController",
});
$stateProvider
.state("about", {
url: "/about",
templateUrl: "about.html",
controller: "AboutController",
});
$stateProvider
.state("contact", {
url: "/contact",
templateUrl: "contact.html",
controller: "ContactController",
});
});
myApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location) {
$scope.message = 'Home Controller!';
});
myApp.controller('AboutController', function($scope) {
$scope.message = 'About Controller.';
});
myApp.controller('ContactController', function($scope) {
$scope.message = 'Contact Controller';
});
```

And if I change to the this (below) it works just fine:

```
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }

  var aboutState = {
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, check this piece of code for the correct syntax of `$stateProvider`

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    }) // no semicolon here
    .state('projects', {
      url: '/projects',
      templateUrl: 'views/projects.html'
    }) // no semicolon here
    // etc
});
```

You shouldn't have `;` in between your states.

Also, you should have them all together and not split up the `$stateProvider`

Also, you should remove the extra `,` you have at the end of each controller declaration in your `$stateProvider` elements.

Here is a working example. 
http://embed.plnkr.co/YKtubLucc5Qa4GwGI77V/

Comment: Hi, there, Ricky, thank you so much!

I remove the extras $stateProvider, the semicolons and "," from the code, but still not working.

Do I have to remove $urlRouterProvider as well?

Comment: Well in my use case, I didn't use specific controllers for each state.

Comment: I'm not sure about `$urlRouterProvider` though, I've only used `$routeProvider` before.

Comment: And honestly, I've also taken ui-router 1.0.0 for a spin not too long ago and it wasn't working for me. I used 0.3.2 and it works perfectly for me so maybe you should give 0.3.2 a try and make sure it works there and then hop over?

Comment: I'm about to give up.
Can you send me via plunker or jsfiddle (or my email: drakhos@gmail.com) a zip with a simple functional sample so I can test and compare?
Something simple with 1 or 2 partials?

Comment: I'll try my best. Give me a few mins. My reward should be an accepted answer green checkmark if I help you get it working right? ;)

Comment: FINALLY!!!
It worked and I was able to use:

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" data-ng-controller="MainController">
      <h1> Olá, Mundo! </h1>
      <h2> Página Home! </h2>
      <h3> Mais um! </h3>
      <p class="">{{ produto.nome }}</p>
      <p class="">{{ produto.preco | currency: "R$" }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Green, green green? ;) Good job! Haha no worries! Keep on coding!

Comment: Did you end up using 1.0.0 or 0.3.2?

Comment: Off course you do!!!
How can I do it? Searching the interface in your profile to do so...

Comment: It's on this question post of yours! Scroll down to my answer and right under the part where you can upvote or downvote, there should be a greyed out checkmark for you to make green and accept the answer! It will be my first real contribution to StackOverflow!!!

Comment: Done with imense pleasure!!!
My name is Marcus, by the way!
It was a great pleasure to meet you!
Thank you so much again!

Comment: Thanks so much! It will help me out along the way for my StackOverflow adventures! My name is Ricky as you probably already found out! Not only did I help a fellow programmer, but because of you, I also learned how to use plunkr!

Comment: I sent you an email so that we can keep in touch!